# Unable to parse values in Go code

Tags: go, xml-parsing, html-parsing

I am starting to use Go and have found that to parse an html or xml document does not have a powerful tool by itself (excuse my ignorance if not).

The fact is that I have the following map (I converted the xml to a map using github.com/clbanning/mxj). It's a XML and HTML Clover report.

What I want is access to the different values: [XML pastebin](https://pastebin.com/46cZNwGC)

My code:

```
    xmlFile, err := os.Open(dir + "\\clover.xml")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error opening file:", err)
        return
    }
    b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(xmlFile)
    defer xmlFile.Close()
                fmt.Println("xmldata:", string(b))

    // get all image tag values - []interface{}
    mapvalue, merr := mxj.NewMapXml(b)
    if merr != nil {
        fmt.Println("merr:", merr.Error())
        return
    }
```

Even in the following way I can subdivide it:

```
    sources, err := mapvalue.ValuesForKey("metrics")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("err:", err.Error())
        return
    }

    for i, src := range sources {
        fmt.Println(i, src)
    }


    fmt.Println(sources[0])
```

It's that particular one I need. But now I can't access every one of the inner values.

> map[-loc:459 -statements:71 -coveredmethods:14 -ncloc:307 -files:12
>   -conditionals:6 -coveredelements:45 -packages:8 -elements:110 -complexity:37 -classes:12 -coveredconditionals:1 -coveredstatements:30 -methods:33]

Is there an easier way to work with the XML and html I have in local?

I added the XML to map result: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/7QNH0TFA)

Comment: The first results I get in Google for golang xml/html parser are https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/ (`encoding/xml` in the standard library) and https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html (`net/html` subrepo) respectively.

Answer (score 2):

GO has an xml parsing library https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/

I have a runnable example here: https://play.golang.org/p/kVG3w4iu3Kl

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/xml"
)

var rawXml = "<metrics coveredelements=\"45\" complexity=\"37\" loc=\"459\" methods=\"33\"/>"

type Metrics struct {
    CoveredElements string `xml:"coveredelements,attr"`
    Complexity      string `xml:"complexity,attr"`
    Loc             string `xml:"loc,attr"`
    Methods         string `xml:"methods,attr"`
}

func main() {
    data := &Metrics{}
    xml.Unmarshal([]byte(rawXml), data)
    fmt.Printf("%+v", data)
}
```

I think that you will find it much easier to work with structs.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this utility to allow me to implement the necessary structures to parse the JSON answers (you can use a converter ). I hope you find it useful too:

https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

You can use a JSON/XML converter online like this: http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson/#.W1cSCNIzZPY.

For the rest I use the same what @Rossiar said in his comment.